# Make jQuery no conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a web widget to be posted on other websites. In the widget it will call jQuery and I dont want the jQuery to conflict with other JavaScript libraries that the website may have installed. When I load the jQuery I would like to call jQuery like this:

```
JQuery_MYSite('id').find('selector');
```

I found out if I do this then `$` will not be able to be used even if the other website uses `$.`

---

When the widget loads it find out if jQuery is loaded. If so, then it will use the `$` to call jQuery. But I know `$` is not unique to just jQuery - other javascript libraries use it. So how can I use my own jQuery prefix with without interfering with the website owners prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the widget it will call jQuery and I dont want the jQuery to
>   conflict with other JavaScript libraries that the website may have
>   installed.

I don't think you can achieve this, because `jQuery.noConflict()` must be called after the other scripts have been loaded. So, if there is no way for you to know about the other scripts, then you won't have a way to avoid the conflicting.

> When the widget loads it find out if jQuery is loaded. If so, then it
>   will use the $ to call jQuery. But I know $ is not unique to just
>   jQuery - other javascript libraries use it. So how can I use my own
>   jQuery prefix with without interfering with the website owners prefix.

Wrap your widget code with an auto-executing anonymous function:

```
(function($){

// your widget code here
// $ will always be jQuery

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I ended up using this implementation. I used the other techniques without success but that technique worked quite well.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myJquery = jQuery.noConflict();
```

then if you want to get fancy:

```
(function($){
    $(".whatever").doSomeStuff();
})(myJquery);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

look at [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
$.noConflict();
(function($){
   // $ is jQuery here
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: AFAIK the `$` inside will be the previous `$` function, not the jQuery

Comment: @KARASZIIstván: sure, he has to add it before any library

Comment: You'd need `jQuery` for the second `$`. Your function is not executing jQuery currently, but the old `$`.

Comment: @genisis: Yes that's possible. Or, just `jQuery(...)`. There is a difference between calling jQuery with a function or the closure you have now, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).